# Where to put this kind of calculation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have started to learn ROR and come along with creating one simple application.

Basicly the app uses calculation for the difference in months between today and another date stored in the database. I have no idea where is the most convenient way to put this kind of code.

Currently, is placed in the view where i subtract today from the date in the database :

```
#user.html.erb

Month difference : <%= (Date.today - @user.date_signed).to_i/30
```

and controller :

```
 class UserController < ApplicationController
  def user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Is there any better way i can accomplish the same ? And if so how ?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It belongs in the model, since you want to handle it as another attribute of user.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def months_since_signed
    (Date.today - self.date_signed).to_i/30
  end
end
```

Then, in your view, just call the method with the instance of `User` as the receiver.

```
Month difference : <%= @user.months_since_signed %>
```